# How to let image that 'pops-up' overlap another div?

Tags: css, spring-mvc, html, z-index

I have made a webapplication with Spring MVC, Hibernate.. etc, but my question is of the css kind. I found a cool picture gallery online which I wanted to use (http://alpatriott.ru/works/album/album-mod.html). So far so good, I have implemented it, only the picture doesn't overlap the lower div.. I'll show a screenshot to clarify..
Can anyone please tell me how to solve this?

If any code is required, tell me and I will post it

[image]

CODE: 
The jsp:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>${album.description}</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div id="content">
        <div class="gallery">
            <c:forEach items="${album.pictures}" var="picture">
                    <a tabindex="1">
                        <img src="<c:url value='/picture/${picture.id}'/>" alt="description" title="${picture.description}" />
                    </a>
            </c:forEach>
            <span class="closed">+</span>
            <span class="closed-layer"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

css:

```
#container {
    height: 62%;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    background-color: #A9E2F3;
    overflow-x: auto;
}

#container #content {
    height: 87%;
    margin: 20px 30px;
    padding: 15px 0 0 5px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    position: relative;
}
```

img style:

```
.gallery {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}

.gallery a{
    display:inline-block;
    width:200px;
    height:141px;
    position:relative;
    border:5px solid #fff;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;


.gallery a img{
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    -webkit-transition-property:width, height, top, bottom, left, right, z-index;
    -webkit-transition-duration:300ms;
    -moz-transition-property:width, height, top, bottom, left, right, z-index;
    -moz-transition-duration:300ms;
    -o-transition-property:width, height, top, bottom, left, right, z-index;
    -o-transition-duration:300ms;
    transition-property:width, height, top, bottom, left, right, z-index;
    transition-duration:300ms;
    position:relative;
    z-index:2;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    cursor:pointer;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}


.gallery a:focus img{
    width:250%;
    height:250%;
    display: block;
    position:absolute;
    box-shadow:0 0 15px 2px #000;
    -moz-box-shadow:0 0 15px 2px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 15px 2px #000;
    -webkit-transition-property:width, height, top, bottom, left, right, z-index;
    -webkit-transition-duration:2s;
    -moz-transition-property:width, height, top, bottom, left, right, z-index;
    -moz-transition-duration:2s;
    -o-transition-property:width, height, top, bottom, left, right, z-index;
    -o-transition-duration:2s;
    transition-property:width, height, top, bottom, left, right, z-index;
    transition-duration:2s;
    cursor:default;
    z-index:25;
}
```

I use a decorator for the page.. Tell me if this isn't enough !

Comment: Yes, code is almost always required.

Answer (score 0):

Put high z-index, like 999 or more, in the image style. That should work.

Comment: OK. I see. Try to put some margin to the gallery class. Or more padding to content id.